# How to manage data integrity for several DML's in single transaction in Servlet and Hibernate based application

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I am using Service(servlet) and DAO pattern for my project. I have to call several DML based DAO methods in one servlce,
So how can I manage transaction so that is any Rintime Exception or server crashes occures the whole DMS's will be rollbacked.

Example as:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
   String id = req.getParameter("studentId");

   StudentDAO sdao=new StudentDAO();

try{
    sdao.updateTable1(Integer.valueOf(id));

    sdao.updateTable2(Integer.valueOf(id));

    sdao.updateTable3(Integer.valueOf(id));
}catch(Exception e){
  // If any exception occurs all changes must be rollback.
}
```

}

@Ben75, I am using a HibernateSessoinFactory class as,

Ya Ben75 I am using HibernateSessionFactory class as 
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

```
private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>(); 
private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry; 

static {
    try {
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            rebuildSessionFactory();
        }
        session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession()
                : null;
        threadLocal.set(session);
    }

    return session;
}
```

}
 and in DAO classes create session as

HibernateSessionFactory.getSession()

Comment: How do you get the hibernate Session in your DAO ? can you post the code ?

Comment: `HibernateSessionFactory.getSession()` ??? which version of hibernate ? Can you also post the code of this method ? (I can't find any doc about this)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle tx manually with hibernate is something like this:

```
Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
   tx = sess.beginTransaction();
   StudentDAO sdao=new StudentDAO();
   sdao.updateTable1(sess, Integer.valueOf(id));
   sdao.updateTable2(sess, Integer.valueOf(id));
   sdao.updateTable3(sess, Integer.valueOf(id));
   tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
  if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
  throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
  sess.close(); //this will also terminate the tx
}
```

Several things to note about this approach:

- you need to reuse the same hibernate session (`sess`) in your dao's. (that's why I add it as an argument to your dao's methods)
- this is the way to manage tx in a non-managed environment (if your code is running in servlet container supporting JTA, there are other ways to deal with tx).
- a framework like Spring can also simplify all transaction management code.

---

One way to manage transaction code in one single place is to use the template pattern. Here is an example (it's just to give you the idea - i.e. not a production ready solution):

```
abstract public class TransactionalTemplate{

    abstract public void runInTransaction();

    public void execute(){
        Session sess = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            runInTransaction();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
            throw e; // or display error message
        }
        finally {
            sess.close(); //this will also terminate the tx
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it :

```
public void businessMethod(){
     new TransactionalTemplate(){
         public void runInTransaction(){
             StudentDAO sdao=new StudentDAO();
             sdao.updateTable1(Integer.valueOf(id));
             sdao.updateTable2(Integer.valueOf(id));
             sdao.updateTable3(Integer.valueOf(id));             }
     }.execute();
}
```

This solution don't use any other framework (only Hibernate), but once again if you use Spring, there is a [transnational support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) using annotations (and there is something similar in [JEE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html))

Comment: Yes this is one way to manage transaction. But, I dont want to declare and use Transaction object and sess.beginTransaction() in every call. So, is there any other option by which we can declare code at one file in project that automatic manages transaction.